# Which of these sentences is grammatically correct?

Tags: repetition

> 1. People who commented before me did not notice.
> 2. People who commented before I did, did not notice.

The usage of two 'did's did not sound good to me, so I was confused.

Comment: They're both fine grammatically. Personally, I might have considered using past perfect, but I do suffer from "past perfect overuse syndrome." Had there been something that had made you think that they were not OK?

Comment: Just that usage of two 'did's  did not sound good to me, so I was confused.

Comment: You should elaborate on that **in your question**. Don't make people _wonder_ why you think something may not be grammatically correct. See our [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) meta post for more tips on how to write questions that are likely to be well-received.

Comment: Mmm, I understand. In that case, the two essentially mean the same, but the second one highlights and emphasizes "people who commented before I did," while the first one does not highlight nor emphasize anything. My point is that there is not one that is better than the other, but there may be one that is more appropriate than the other, depending on the context and situation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the second sentence has a tautology. Two consecutive 'did's make the phrase not very nice. So I would choose the first sentence as a correct one (since I did not see any mistakes in it):

> People who commented before me did not notice.

Comment: Not a tautology, just *horror aequi*, dislike of juxtaposed repetition.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Professionals perhaps know much better than me.)